# PHP- Validate on certain fields

Tags: php

I've a form,in the form only few fields are mandatory.When a fields is not mandatory,it should not check for empty data validation.If the non mandatory field contain data then it shoudl check the data,validation should happen only when data present.

My below code check for all fields.For eg:Say phone is not mandatory in below code,how to change the code.

```
$validate = array(
    array($x, '/^[a-z\d ]{4,20}$/i', "Please enter valid name."),
    array($y, '/^[a-z\d ]{4,20}$/i', "Please enter a real category."),
    array($phone, '/^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3}[-. ]? [0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$/' , "Please enter a valid phone number")
);

$error = '';
foreach ($validate as $validation)
{
    if (!preg_match($validation[1],$validation[0]))
    {
       $error .= $validation[2]; 
    }
}

if($error != '')
{
    echo $error;
    exit;
}
```

Comment on this post,if it is not clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if at least required fields have been submitted, you can check whether they have been set and have a truthy value using the `isset` and `empty` functions.

For example:

```
if ( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) && 
     ! empty($_POST['username']) && ! empty($_POST['password']) ) {
    // validation here
}
```

That would check if the username and password fields were submitted and have a value, whereas for example an email field wouldn't necessarily have been filled in for the above condition to return true.

Comment: :In my above code, would like to validate on non mandatory fields,if an user enters data.can you tell me,how i do that.

Comment: You could use the exact same logic. Within the code block I provided, check if for example $_POST['phone'] was set and has a value, and handle the validation accordingly.

Comment: :You're not clear with what i'm looking.A form has some fields which is not mandatory.If user enters data,i should perform validation.Is that clear.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. The logic I am providing you with is exactly whay you're looking for. Like I did above, you can do something like `if (isset($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['phone']))` and perform the validation if that returns true, i.e. if the phone field has been filled in. And if it has not been filled in, the condition will return false meaning there's no need for validation.

Comment: :if it is filled,it has to be validated.

Comment: Yes... I think you're not getting the logic here. I just provided you with the logic to check if a field was filled in. You already know the logic to do the validation itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the mandatory fields before hand I'll suggest you group them in an array and test for based on the current key. If a key is in not mandatory but holds value you can test otherwise do your regular check.

```
$error = '';
$mandatoryFields = array('key1', 'key2' 'key3');

foreach ($validate as $validation)
{
    if (!in_array($validation[0], $mandatoryFields) && strlen(trim($validation[0])) > 0) 
    {
        // There is data in a non mandatory field.
        // Perform your test.
    } 
    else {
        // Do your regular test.
        if (!preg_match($validation[1],$validation[0]))
        {
           $error .= $validation[2]; 
        }
    }
}
```

You can give this a try.